# Iterate property file based on a key

Tags: java, properties, iteration

I have a property file and I would like to iterate each block if there is a key present 'Test_Name'. From each Test, I have to get the value like A, B and I have to write A+B in each set. What will be the simple iteration approach here using Java.

```
 //Property File

    Test_Name_1 = Test 1
    data1=A
    data2=B

    Test_Name_2 = Test 2
    data3=A
    data4=B

    Test_Name_3 = Test 3
    data5=A
    data6=B
```

Update: @jgitter
I saw some examples to iterate property file like below. But I am not sure how do I customize this for my need.

```
for(String key: propfilekey.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key  +" :: "+ propfilekey.get(key));
        }
```

Comment: The Properties class has facilities for auto-loading files in the classpath and they are not iterable, i.e. there is no preservation of ordering.  You are needlessly adding complexity.  Why not create a new property file for each test case?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use xml files and use a standard xml parser, or json for that matter.  A standard Properties file just doesn't fit this use-case.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'block' in a property file. You need to redesign your input.

Comment: Re your edit, you can't 'customize it for [your] need', as you've been told twice already. Three times now.

Comment: OK, I'll change the structure of the property file.